# Run a Url without opening browser every one hour

Tags: c#, cron, scheduler

I have a project in c# dot net, there is a handler file where i have created a function that takes some data from outlook and update a specific table in my database. I have to run this every hour. I searched and found i need to create a new console project which i want to avoid. I tried calling the url using curl_call in a PHP page as i have php application on IIS, but i am getting SSO issue. If there is any way to run the URL (http://myApp.myCompany.com/handler/getDetails.ashx) in batch at 1 hour interval.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a task in the Windows task Scheduler that runs once per hour, and have that task run the following command

`powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command “ (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://myApp.myCompany.com/handler/getDetails.ashx')”`

Comment: The above is the correct way to do it in my locale, but it is probably different for you. There are differences between the quotation marks, that you have to experiment with a bit.